# Fitting Mixture Distribution of Poisson and Negative Binomial (Delaporte Distribution)

Tags: regression, distributions, count-data

I am trying to fit a model to some simulated data. The idea is to use ML-Estimation. However, I am totally lost.

I have a dependent variable which is a sum of two (unknown) variables. The first part is Poisson-Distributed and the second part is Negative Binomial Distributed. In the sum this leads to a [Delaporte model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaporte_distribution).

I already implemented parts of the model based on a log likelihood-function. However, I am missing the weighting matrix.

```
set.seed(1234)
x1 <- runif(5000, min = 0, max = 5)
x2 <- runif(5000, min = 0, max = 5)

# Model 1
## beta0=0.5, beta1=0.3, beta2=0.4, eta=0.5, delta=2

alpha1  <- rgamma(5000, shape = 0.5, rate = 0.5)
lambda1 <- alpha1 * exp(0.5 + 0.3 * x1 + 0.4 * x2 )
Q1      <- matrix(1:5000, ncol=1)
for (i in 1:5000){
  Q1[i] <- rpois(1, lambda=lambda1)
}
Q1 <- apply(Q1, 1,as.numeric) # converts matrix object to numeric vector
u1 <- rpois(5000, lambda=0.5)
y1 <- Q1 + u1

# ML Estimation
n     <- length(x1)
nlogL <- function(par) {
  n     <- length(x1)
  beta  <- par[1:3]
  eta   <- par[4]
  delta <- par[5]
  -(-n*eta*log(eta)*n*mean(y1)+sum(delta*log(delta/(delta+lambda)))+sum(log(???)))
}
par0 <- as.vector(c(0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 1.3))
out<-nlm(nlogL,p=par0, hessian = TRUE)
out
```

Where 
$???$ is needed!
$$
??? = \sum_{q_i = 1}^{y_i} w(q_i)
$$
\begin{align}
w &= w(q_i) \\
  &= w(q_i| \beta, \eta, \delta) \\
  &= \frac{\Gamma(q_i + \delta)}{\Gamma(\delta)\Gamma(Q_i+1} \bigg[\frac{\lambda_i}{\eta(\lambda_i+\delta)}\bigg]^q_i \frac{1}{\Gamma(y_1-q_i+1)}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Delaporte](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Delaporte/index.html) package for R? Try using `optim` or `nloptr` to minimize the NLL as returned by `ddelap` in that package. It may take some time as the Delaporte has no closed form and requires summation.

For example:

```
set.seed(6541321)    
library(nloptr)
library(Delaporte)
POIS <- rpois(5000, lambda = 4)
summary(POIS)
>   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    3.00    4.00    4.03    5.00   13.00 
NB <- rnbinom(5000, size = 3, mu = 15) ## Implies alpha = 3 and beta = 5
summary(NB)
>   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00    8.00   13.00   15.29   20.00   81.00 
Del_Test <- POIS + NB
summary(Del_Test)
>   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.00   12.00   17.00   19.32   25.00   86.00 
Inits <- MoMdelap(Del_Test)
Inits ## Method of Moments estimate (if reasonable)
>[1] 2.777264 5.337955 4.497891
Del_NLL <- function(pars, data) {
  return(-sum(ddelap(data, pars[[1]], pars[[2]], pars[[3]], log = TRUE)))
}
Del_Fit <- nloptr(x0 = Inits, eval_f = Del_NLL, data = Del_Test, lb = c(0, 0, 0), opts=list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_SBPLX", maxeval = 10000))
Del_Fit
>Call:
nloptr(x0 = Inits, eval_f = Del_NLL, lb = c(0, 0, 0), opts = list(algorithm = "NLOPT_LN_SBPLX",     maxeval = 10000), data = Del_Test)


Minimization using NLopt version 2.4.0 

NLopt solver status: 4 ( NLOPT_XTOL_REACHED: Optimization stopped because xtol_rel or xtol_abs (above) was reached. )

Number of Iterations....: 2250 
Termination conditions:  maxeval: 10000 
Number of inequality constraints:  0 
Number of equality constraints:    0 
Optimal value of objective function:  18061.4279834719 
Optimal value of controls: 3.026119 5.1027 3.882561
```